# Scan full discord member list and change nicknames

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am looking for a way to scan my full server online member list every hour, and change any cancer nicknames. Like names with "!" at the start or "`" pretty much all non letter/number characters. I am using discord.js with all intents enabled. If you can help I will appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`GuildMemberManger.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) provides the functionality you require.

```
members = await <Guild>.members.fetch({query: 'querystring'})
```

All members with querystring in their username will be returned, in a collection.
After that you can iterate through the collection and do whatever you want.

If you want more control over the conditions you should filter the members cache collection with your own conditions.

```
condition = (member) => member.nickname.length == 3 //Finds members with 3 letter nicknames.
members = await <Guild>.members.cache.filter(condition)
```

Comment: Note that the cache may not have all members*

Comment: yeah might not have